# When setting a Journey Builder Goal, what does "population" refer to?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, goals

In Journey Builder, when I want to set a goal for a journey, I can choose to target x "% of the population".

The "term" population can be rather confusing though. For instance, there is also the notion of "populations" inside Data Designer.

So what does it refer to?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A "population" within a journey is unrelated to the concept of populations within the Data Designer (the latter is sometimes also referred to as a "root data extension relationship").

As explained by SFMC within Data Designer:

> Use a new population to segment a large group of contacts within your account. The Marketing Cloud recommends including only two to three populations within an account. Create a population only when you need to address a large and specific segment of your contacts.

Instead, a **"population" within a journey simply refers to all the people who have entered that journey**. This is the number displayed on top of your "flow" within the editor, and can also be toggled in the top right:

[image]